# cpp program for SIFT feature extraction

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, opencv, mat

I am using the MATLAB to process the images currently to extract the features of the image and compare it with a reference image. The MATLAB is installed on a windows system.
**Now I want to write a cpp program for SIFT in a linux machine. How to use the MATLAB commands there?**

**Problem:** Can I use the executable created in a windows machine in linux? if so how?

Is OPENCV the only option in linux or is there any other way to implement SIFT?

regards,
shiksha

Comment: you cannot use a binary file compiled for windows in a Linux environment unless you are running some sort of virtualization layer that simulates windows.

Comment: No, there is a http://www.vlfeat.org/ and http://robwhess.github.io/opensift/. However, you cannon use matlab commands from cpp linux program.